# Tag synonym request: volley and android-volley

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The [android-volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-volley) and [volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/volley) tags are both being used for Android's Volley library; they should be synonyms.

I'd do the suggestion myself, but I'm missing the score of 5 or more on the tag.